# Update not working on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04

When I run the update command using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then I am getting error saying:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

I tried a lot for fixing this using different forums but all in vain.

Please suggest how I can fix it.

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It looks like you have a malformed line in there.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot add the content so I gave link of the file.

Comment: @ramkrishna Why do you have `|security.ubuntu.com` in your `sources.list`? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Just noticed another problem, will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was trying but it was showing some problem with sed command.

Comment: Commands fixed now, forgot the 's' at the beginning of the `sed` command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. In the sources lines, you shouldn't have any lines with `in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com` in them.

Save a backup of your sources file with:

```
cp -a /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

Then use `sed` to correct your current sources file:

```
sed -i 's/in.archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/in.archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

followed by

```
sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/security.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Your `apt-get` commands should work properly after this.

Actually I've only just noticed that all of the India mirrors (in.archive.ubuntu.com) are commented out, these commands have fixed those entries anyway, but they're not being used.

The problem was coming from the wrong entries concerning the security updates.
You will receive security updates now when you update, and the rest of your updates will come from the main Ubuntu mirrors, it may be quicker to update from your local mirrors, which are the `in.archive.ubuntu.com` entries.